# Prove that $3(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a)\geq(a^2c+b^2a+c^2b)^2$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math, triangles, buffalo-way

> Let $\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{c}$ be sides-lengths of a triangle. Prove that:
> $$3(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a)\geq(a^2c+b^2a+c^2b)^2$$

I tried to apply the  way like the proof of the following inequality, but without success.

Let $\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{c}$ be sides-lengths of a triangle. Prove that:
$$2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)\geq3+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}.$$
Proof.

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2c-a^2b-abc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-abc)-\sum_{cyc}(b^3-2ab^2+a^2b)\geq0$$ or
$$\frac{a+b+c}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2-\sum_{cyc}b(a-b)^2\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+c-b)\geq0.$$

Lemma.

Let $x+y+z\geq0$ and $xy+xz+yz\geq0$. Prove that:
$$(b-c)^2x+(a-c)^2y+(b-c)^2z\geq0.$$
Proof of the lemma.

Let $x+y\geq0$.

If $x+y=0$ then $xy+xz+yz=-x^2\geq0$,

which gives $x=y=0$ and $z\geq0$, which says that

$(b-c)^2x+(a-c)^2y+(a-b)^2z\geq0$ is true.

Thus, we can assume that $x+y>0$ and we need to prove that
$$(b-c)^2x+(a-b+b-c)^2y+(a-b)^2z\geq0$$ or
$$(x+y)(b-c)^2+2y(a-b)(b-c)+(y+z)(a-b)^2\geq0,$$
for which it's enough to prove that
$$y^2-(x+y)(y+z)\leq0$$ or
$$xy+xz+yz\geq0,$$
which ends a proof of the lemma.

Now, $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+c-b)=a+b+c>0$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}(a+b-c)(a+c-b)=\sum_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)=$$
$$=(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a})>0,$$
which ends the proof by the lemma.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$3(a^5b + b^5c + c^5a) \ge (a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)^2$$

$$\iff 3(abc)^2\left[\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^3 \cdot \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^3 \cdot \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^3 \cdot \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2\right] \ge (abc)^2\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}\right)^2$$

Let $\dfrac{a}{b} = x, \dfrac{b}{c} = y, \dfrac{c}{a} = z \implies xyz = 1$.

$$\iff 3\left(\frac{x^2y}{z} + \frac{y^2z}{x} + \frac{z^2x}{y}\right) \ge (x + y + z)^2$$

, which can be proven by using the Chebyshev inequality, the AM-GM inequality and the Cauchy inequality (which applications can be used in the order listed).

Comment: If your solution is true, so the starting inequality is true for all positives $a$, $b$ and $c$, which is not so. Try $c\rightarrow0^+$.

Comment: I used the Chebyshev inequality, which only works when supposed $x^2 \ge y^2 \ge z^2$ and $\dfrac{y}{z} \ge \dfrac{z}{x} \ge \dfrac{x}{y} \implies \dfrac{a^2}{b^2} \ge \dfrac{b^2}{c^2} \ge \dfrac{c^2}{a^2}$ and $\dfrac{ab}{c^2} \ge \dfrac{bc}{a^2} \ge \dfrac{ca}{b^2}$.

Comment: Mr. @MichaelRozenberg , how about your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Remark: Since no complete solution is available, I give the solution by the Buffalo Way. Hope to see nice solutions.

Let $a = (u+v)^2, b = (v+w)^2, c = (w+u)^2$ for $u, v, w > 0$ (Ravi Substitution). It suffices to prove that
$g(u,v,w) \ge 0$ where $g(u,v,w)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $12$.

WLOG, assume that $w = \min(u, v, w)$. Let $v = w + s$ and $u = w + t$ for $s, t\ge 0$.
It suffices to prove that
$$q_{10}w^{10} + q_9w^9 + q_8w^8 + q_7w^7 + q_6w^6 + q_5w^5 + q_4w^4 + q_3w^3 + q_2w^2 + q_1w + q_0 \ge 0.$$
It is not hard to prove that $q_{10}, q_9, \cdots, q_0\ge 0$.
I do not give the expressions of $q_i, \forall i$. If someone uses the Computer Algebra Systems (CAS), it is an easy job.

Comment: Where can I find CAS ?

Comment: @GiangNguyễnĐặngThanh  Mathematica, Maple, Matlab, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

The River Li's solution we can rewrite so.

Let $c=\max\{a,b,c\}$, $a=(x+u)^2,$ $b=(x+v)^2$ and $c=(x+u+v)^2,$ where $x>0$,$u\geq0$ and $v\geq0.$

Thus, $$3(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a)-(a^2c+b^2a+c^2b)^2=$$
$$=60(u^2-uv+v^2)x^{10}+6(58u^3+37u^2v-11uv^2+58v^3)x^9+$$
$$+(959u^4+2078u^3v+1149u^2v^2+350uv^3+959u^4)x^8+$$
$$+8(207u^5+750u^4v+922u^3v^2+428u^2v^3+133uv^4+207u^5)x^7+$$
$$+4(493u^6+2500u^5v+4514u^4v^2+3866u^3v^3+1281u^2v^4+338uv^5+493v^6)x^6+$$
$$+16(105u^7+687u^6v+1602u^5v^2+1936u^4v^3+1183u^3v^4+249u^2v^5+57uv^6+105v^7)x^5+$$
$$+8(129u^8+1035u^7v+2943u^6v^2+4478u^5v^3+3925u^4v^4+1705u^3v^5+150u^2v^6+33uv^7+129v^8)x^4+$$
$$+2(229u^9+2130u^8v+7152u^7v^2+12968u^6v^3+14432u^5v^4+9422u^4v^5+2748u^3v^6-252u^2v^7-27uv^8+225v^9)x^3+$$
$$+(133u^{10}+1438u^9v+5586u^8v^2+11696u^7v^3+15552u^6v^4+13164u^5v^5+6410u^4v^6+928u^3v^7-529u^2v^8-68uv^9+133v^{10})x^2+$$
$$+4(u^2+uv+v^2)(6u^9+66u^8v+247u^7v^2+443u^6v^3+470u^5v^4+271u^4v^5+37u^3v^6-44u^2v^7-11uv^8+6v^9)x+$$
$$+2(u^2+uv+v^2)^3(u^3+5u^2v+2uv^2-v^3)^2\geq0.$$
The inequality in my open post by the same way gives:
$$2(a^2c+b^2a+c^2b)-3abc-a^2b-b^2c-c^2a=$$
$$=4(u^2-uv+v^2)x^4+2(6u^3-7u^2v+5uv^2+6v^3)x^3+$$
$$+(13u^4-14u^3v-9u^2v^2+34uv^3+13v^4)x^2+$$
$$+2(3u^5-2u^4v-10u^3v^2+8u^2v^3+13uv^4+3v^5)x+(u^3-3uv^2-v^3)^2\geq0.$$
I think, from the expression $2(u^2+uv+v^2)^3(u^3+5u^2v+2uv^2-v^3)^2$ we can learn that maybe there is a solution for the starting inequality by the lemma.

Comment: Still a complicated proof.